# Can StringBuilder be emulated in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to emulate StringBuilder behavior in an XSL. Is there a way to do this. It seems pretty hard given the fact that XSLT is a functional programming language

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Emulate StringBuilder"? StringBuilder does a number of things, the most common of which is appending to strings, but it can also replace substrings, search for substring, count its length, etc. What in particular are you looking for? Just appending? Searching? What?

Comment: I am looking for just the appending functionality.

Comment: It is not possible to change the value of a variablein XSLT, once it has been defined. This is by definition because XSLT is a functional language. This is not to say that there aren't fast implementations of *immutable* strings (even faster than the .NET string) -- read more about this in my answer

Comment: You can't change a variable but you can use recursion

Comment: @Varun Mahajan: Being a bit more responsive generally is a good thing. It improves answer quality, adds missing details, keeps moods cool and last but not least: It shows respect for those who spend their time answering your question. You could have looked into this question at least once today.

Comment: @Tomalak. My job timings allowed me to have a look on this question just now only. And I appreciate your concern a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: @Varun Mahajan: This started to get out of hand a bit, so thanks for coming back at last. ;-)

Comment: for my part I apologise for that, I just shouldn't have engaged - just glad this question is resolved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the accumulting concats quite simply with just a little bit of recursion if you're looking at a node-set (so long as you can construct the xpath to find the node-set), doing this so you can add arbitrary bits and pieces in and out of the flow it starts getting messy.

Try this for starters (does join as well):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="s">
        <xsl:call-template name="stringbuilder">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="*" /><!-- your path here -->
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:value-of select="$s" /><!-- now contains a big concat string -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="stringbuilder">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:param name="join" select="''"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$data/*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(position()=1)">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($join,child::text())"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="child::text()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

All manner of extensions to that may be required: perhaps you want to trim, perhaps you want to tunnel through hierarchies as well. I'm not sure a bulletproof general solution exists.

Comment: The $join variable does not serve any purpose. It is confusing and misleading! Instead of "concat($join,child::text())" use just "text()". The whole <xsl:for-each> is unnecessary. use a single: "xsl:copy-of select='$data/text()'"

Comment: You really are a special kind of troll aren't you Dimitre? VERY VERY CLEARLY the join parameter is optional (see where it has a select?) which allows the builder to function as a .join method (see where I say "does join as well"?) which requires the loop, which provides expansion ("for starters"?).

Comment: @annakata I completely don't understand what is "VERY VERY CLEARLY" to you. I feel very curious as to what this may be. Can you explain and provide a little example of the use of the "join" parameter?

Comment: Sure. If I was to include <xsl:with-param name="join" select="'TROLL'"/> on a set of text a,b,c,d it would product the result "aTROLLbTROLLcTROLLd"

Comment: Now I see what you meant. Is indeed a downvote and several signals that this was not understandable, necessary to make you finally explain what you meant? Your answer will benefit greatly if you explain *in it* the intended use of the "join" parameter. Not much to do with the original append f-ty q.

Comment: You're happy to explain *finger-trees* with a handy *white-paper* but string joining baffles you? Do I *really* need to explain how "join" relates to "string"? If you know XSLT as you claim how is it you don't understand optional params? My answer would benefit from you not being here.

Comment: Actually whatever, I'm done with this pointless merry-go-round. Downvote away, I'm not feeding you any more.

Comment: Thanks @annakata. And @annakata and @Dimitre, cool down a bit. Thanks to you both

Comment: "string-join" and "join" are very different things. An answer will benefit Greatly if more attention is paid on explaining and being precise vs sloppy. If one really wants to provide an useful answer, dropping just a line without an example isn't that at all. I think you may do better.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [`concat()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xquery-operators-20021115/#func-concat) and [`string-join()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xquery-operators-20021115/#func-string-join) functions, maybe that's what you are after.

Comment: I am looking for just the appending functionality. And that means I want to store the result after appending in the same variable

Comment: No, this won't be possible. Variables are immutable in XSLT, you cannot change them. You can maybe use recursion to get a similar result. What exactly do you want to do? Can you post some code to your question?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use all available [standard XPath 2.0 string functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string-functions)**, such as [**`concat()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat), [**`substring()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring), [**`substring-before()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-before), [**`substring-after()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-after), **[`string-join()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join)**, ..., etc.

However, **in case you need a very fast implementation of strings (even faster than the .NET string class) you'll probably be interested in the [C# implementation](http://dnovatchev.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!44B0A32C2CCF7488!582.entry) of the [finger-tree data structure](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.pdf)** and [**the extension functions I provided**](http://dnovatchev.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!44B0A32C2CCF7488!672.entry) for the Saxon XSLT processor that wrap the finger-tree-based string.